# Contents of an untyped object copied into vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, arrays, void, memcpy

I'm trying to write the contents of an untyped object that holds the bytes of an image into a vector filled with unsigned char. Sadly, i cannot get it to work. Maybe someone could point me in the right direction?

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
vector<unsigned char> SQLiteDB::BlobData(int clmNum){
   //i get the data of the image
   const void* data = sqlite3_column_blob(pSQLiteConn->pRes, clmNum);
   vector<unsigned char> bytes;
   //return the size of the image in bytes
   int size = getBytes(clNum);
   unsigned char b[size];
   memcpy(b, data, size);
   for(int j=0;j<size,j++){
      bytes.push_back(b[j])M
   }
   return bytes;
}
```

If i try to trace the contents of the bytes vector it's all empty.

So the question is, how can i get the data into the vector?

Comment: try std::copy( std::begin( data ), std::end( data ), bytes.begin() );

Comment: @Ben: `std::copy` requires that the destination is large enough (which it wouldn't be in above code).

Comment: Why don't you just cast the pointer instead of using `memcpy`? (You might want to use copy and paste instead of re-typing your code - it's hard to tell bugs from typos otherwise.)

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Then resize it first?

Comment: @molbdnilo Not sure what you mean, I'm not really that good at C++ (as you can probably tell.) do you mean something like `bytes = (vector<unsigned char>) data`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the vector's constructor that takes a couple of iterators:

```
const unsigned char* data = static_cast<const unsigned char*>(sqlite3_column_blob(pSQLiteConn->pRes, clmNum));
vector<unsigned char> bytes(data, data + getBytes(clNum));
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly write into the `vector`, no need for additional useless copies:

```
bytes.resize(size);
memcpy(bytes.data(), data, size);
```

Instead of a copy, this has a zero-initialisation, so using the constructor like Maxim demonstrates or `vector::insert` is better.

```
const unsigned char* data = static_cast<const unsigned char*>(sqlite3_column_blob(pSQLiteConn->pRes, clmNum));
bytes.insert(data, data + getBytes(clNum));
```

Comment: This has an additional useless zero-initialisation. `std::copy` or `vector::insert` (or the range constructor) would be better.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Are you sure `std::copy` would be more than a replacement for `memcpy` in this case? (Specifically, that it would enlarge the vector, and without initialising the new elements?) Cannot see how that could be true. Incorporated `vector::insert`.

Comment: It certainly *should* avoid the zero-initialisation done by `resize`. Whether it actually does is a quality of implementation issue, but I'd be surprised if any sensible implementation didn't.

Comment: "Cannot see how that could be true." - copying to a `back_inserter` will (in principle) insert new elements using `push_back`, so they will be initialised directly with no need to zero-initialise first. (There might be an issue of more reallocations than necessary, if you don't call `reserve` first, and the implementation might not be cunning enough to optimise repeated back-insertion to a simple copy, so `insert` would be a better option).

Comment: Found the `back_inserter`. Something one must order separately. I think i read that part long ago... +1